# Don't allow user to override value of DerefMut struct, but allow it to execute mutable function on it

Tags: rust

I'm currently develloping my own library for vectors and matrices, and to simplify my life, I defined my Matrix to be a Vec of Vector, and defined the Deref trait as such:

```rs
pub struct Matrix(Vec<RowVector>);

impl Deref for Matrix {
    type Target = [RowVector];

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Matrix {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.0
    }
}
```

This work like a charm, but it has one flaw: you can override one row to be a RowVector of a different size of the rest, which is obviously VERY BAD.

Am I doomed? is there a solution to disallow the overwrite but allow to mutate the Vector ?

Comment: Instead of implementing `Deref`, provide custom wrappers.

Comment: like instead of having deref, implementing the Index trait and take a tuple of indices ? @ChayimFriedman

Comment: I want the API to be as clean as possible, not having to use long function name juste to get a value

Comment: Yeah, that is what I had in mind.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman well I just implemented it, it is as clean and I did not had to change too much code, I was searching for a way to make this way work other than searching for an better way to do it, thx for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement `Index` and `IndexMut` over a pair `(usize, usize)`:

```rust
use std::ops::{IndexMut, Index};

pub struct Matrix(Vec<Vec<usize>>);


impl Index<(usize, usize)> for Matrix {
    type Output = usize;

    fn index(&self, index: (usize, usize)) -> &Self::Output {
        self.0.get(index.0).unwrap().get(index.1).unwrap()
    }
}

impl IndexMut<(usize, usize)> for Matrix {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: (usize, usize)) -> &mut Self::Output {
        self.0.get_mut(index.0).unwrap().get_mut(index.1).unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4dd85370f6a23ec2faa8733069cd28c7)

**Disclaimer**: Please take into account that using `unwrap` is not clean here. Either assert lengths, deal with options or at least use `expect` depending on your needs.

Comment: thx for the feedback, It actually is the way I went for